# Dynamically Link Images - Power Point

Tags: image, powerpoint, dynamic-linking

I have a slide presentation with the same image on 10 of the 20 slides. When I rebuild with the presentation for another user I have to change those 10 slides to update the image.

Is there a way to have one of the images be the master image and all other link back to the master so I can update just the one image ?

Cheers,
Fox

Answer (score 1):

This is more a question for SuperUser than StackOverflow, but since we're here ...

To insert the first instance of the picture, choose Insert | Picture. Browse to the picture you want, select it then instead of clicking Insert in the dialog box, click the triangle to the right of Insert; from the dropdown that appears, choose "Insert and Link".

Now copy the picture to wherever else you want to use it in the presentation.  Since the picture is linked, PPT will update the presentation with the latest version of the picture when you open the PPT file.  But a full copy of the picture is also embedded, so if the linked file isn't available or the link breaks, the picture won't turn into a red x.